# minlength doesn't work with jquery validation

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am using jquery validation in zend 2.
All the other validation types are working except minlength.
Here is the form code:

```
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'usr_name',

        'attributes' => array(
            'type'  => 'text',
            'id' => 'firstName',
            'class'  => 'form-control',

        // jquery validation rules:
            'required'  => 'true',
            'minlength'  => '2',
            'maxlength'  => '20',
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Name',
        ),
    ));
```

Here is the js code:

```
 $('.form-validation').each(function () {
     $(this).validate({


    errorElement: "span",
    errorClass: "help-block",   

    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        $(element).attr('style', "border-radius: 5px; border:#FF0000 1px solid;");
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).addClass('valid').closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        $(element).attr('style', "border-radius: 4px; border:1px solid #ccc;");
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        $(error).attr('style', "color: #FF0000;");
        if ( element.prop('type') === 'checkbox') {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }

  });
 });
```

**UPDATE :**
This is the html generated:

```
<input name="usr_name" type="text" required="required" maxlength="20" id="firstName" class="form-control" value="" aria-required="true">
```

**LOOK AT THIS:**

[Strange, how can it be possible!](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/3770)

Comment: Instead of showing the Zend code, show the relevant  HTML markup as seen by the browser.

Comment: Then clearly this is a problem with how Zend creates `input` elements and nothing to do with jQuery Validate.

Comment: `maxlength` cannot be working either... notice that it also skipped creating the `maxlength` attribute.  Clearly, it seems that certain HTML5 attributes are a problem for Zend to generate.

Comment: `minlength` and `maxlength` are perfectly valid HTML5 `input` attributes!  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following [article](http://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/3770).

Which is very strange how **ZF2** people consider this a logic!!

So for an ugly workaround I injected `minlength` `attribute` in the needed elements in the following way:

```
 $('.minLength').each(function () {
     $(this).attr("minlength", "8");
 });
```

Where `minLength` is a class added optionally to the needed elements to give **jquery** the opportunity to work on them properly!